# How to type keys

Tags: support

[image: Pic-1]

How do I type the F3 thingy (and the bold version) like the one above? Is there any formatting used?

[ADD] Using `<kbd>` tag only produces this effect: <kbd>F3</kbd>, but not the image above. Does it have variations on different sites?

Comment: There are different formats for different sites ([meta.ubuntu.se] is different to [ubuntu.se]). That image is the old style, and the style of [meta.ubuntu.se].

Comment: bold and italic is achieved by standard markdown inside, try: `<kbd>**F3**</kbd>` and `<kbd>*F3*</kbd>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `<kbd></kbd>` tags to wrap around such text.

<kbd>Ctrl + 1</kbd>

Also see [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)